# How to find the probability that you will wait for at least 10 seconds on exactly 3 of those days?

Tags: probability

Suppose that the waiting time X (in seconds) for the pedestrian signal at a particular street crossing is a ranadom variable with the following pdf:

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      \frac{4}{61}(1-x/61)^3 &  0 \leq x < 61\\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
$$

If you use this crossing every day for the next 6 days, what is the probability that you will wait for at least 10 seconds on exactly 3 of those days?

My attempt:

$$\int_{10}^{61} \! \frac{4}{61}(1-x/61)^3 \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

$$\approx 0.48860$$

Then since we need the probability on exactly 3 of the 6 days I calculated:

$$0.48860(3)$$

$$\approx .11664$$

The answer is wrong, and am looking for someone to help show me where I went wrong with my thinking/logic. Is any of what I did correct?

Comment: I would think that this becomes a Bernoulli trial. You have $$\dbinom{6}{3}(0.48860)^3(1-0.48860)^3 \approx 0.31201$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe You are right. Thank you so much! At least I had the integration part right.